# Repeat each identifier over date range

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably a pretty simple question but I am very new to python so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Let's say I have a pandas df of unique identifiers 101, 201, 301 and a monthly date range. I would like to combine these so that each identifier shows up once at each date (so if the monthly data were 12 months, the resulting data frame would be 36 rows).

```py
id = {'unique':[101,201,301]}
id_df = pd.DataFrame(id)
month = pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', end = '2021-1-01', freq='M')
```

I know it's a pretty easy question but any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first assign a new column `dates` with each row being `month` and then `explode` it:

```
id_df["dates"] = [month] * len(id_df)
id_df = id_df.explode("dates", ignore_index=True)
```

where we `ignore_index` so that resultant index is `0..N-1`.

after first operation:

```
   unique                                              dates
0     101  DatetimeIndex(["2020-01-31", "2020-02-29", "20...
1     201  DatetimeIndex(["2020-01-31", "2020-02-29", "20...
2     301  DatetimeIndex(["2020-01-31", "2020-02-29", "20...
```

and then

```
>>> id_df

    unique      dates
0      101 2020-01-31
1      101 2020-02-29
2      101 2020-03-31
3      101 2020-04-30
4      101 2020-05-31
5      101 2020-06-30
6      101 2020-07-31
7      101 2020-08-31
8      101 2020-09-30
9      101 2020-10-31
10     101 2020-11-30
11     101 2020-12-31
12     201 2020-01-31
13     201 2020-02-29
14     201 2020-03-31
15     201 2020-04-30
16     201 2020-05-31
17     201 2020-06-30
18     201 2020-07-31
19     201 2020-08-31
20     201 2020-09-30
21     201 2020-10-31
22     201 2020-11-30
23     201 2020-12-31
24     301 2020-01-31
25     301 2020-02-29
26     301 2020-03-31
27     301 2020-04-30
28     301 2020-05-31
29     301 2020-06-30
30     301 2020-07-31
31     301 2020-08-31
32     301 2020-09-30
33     301 2020-10-31
34     301 2020-11-30
35     301 2020-12-31
```

(you can do `id_df = id_df.sort_values("dates", ignore_index=True, kind="mergesort")` afterwards to sort with respect to dates in a stable manner.)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! I do my data manipulation in R for the most part but I have some models running there and decided to try this in python instead. Definitely don't think I would have figured this out on my own. Thanks again! I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @tfr950 glad to be of help! I hope you'll have fun writing Python.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame(itertools.product([101,201,301],
                               pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', end = '2021-1-01', freq='M')),
             columns=['unique', 'dates'],
            )
```

output:

```
    unique  dates
0   101 2020-01-31
1   101 2020-02-29
2   101 2020-03-31
3   101 2020-04-30
4   101 2020-05-31
5   101 2020-06-30
6   101 2020-07-31
7   101 2020-08-31
8   101 2020-09-30
9   101 2020-10-31
10  101 2020-11-30
11  101 2020-12-31
12  201 2020-01-31
13  201 2020-02-29
…
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id_df.merge(month.to_series(name="dates"),how='cross')
```

output:

```
    unique  dates
0   101 2020-01-31
1   101 2020-02-29
2   101 2020-03-31
3   101 2020-04-30
4   101 2020-05-31
5   101 2020-06-30
6   101 2020-07-31
7   101 2020-08-31
8   101 2020-09-30
9   101 2020-10-31
10  101 2020-11-30
11  101 2020-12-31
12  201 2020-01-31
13  201 2020-02-29
…
```